# Where do I find the "Security code" to test "Commerce PayPal WPP Credit Card" with my "sandbox buyer account"

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I am on Drupal 7.59 and using [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and [Commerce PayPal](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) modules.

I am at testing step, using my PayPal sandbox accounts (buyer and facilitator) to check if my PayPal classic and **PayPal Credit Card** payment methods work fine.

1. On PayPal classic I used WPS, and it works well
2. On PayPal Credit Card, I am using WPP, but **something is missing somewhere**.

**About my PayPal WPP Credit Card (2)**

All configuration is good, all the API credential that I have is correct. But one is missing : the **Security code**. In all tutorial I've watched, nobody talks about that field "Security Code". But it is a **required field**!. Whithout it I can not continue payment process which PayPal CB.

Can't anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put in any number that matches the card type - e.g. 111 or Visa / Mastercard / Discover or 1111 for American Express. As far as I know, the PayPal API will accept any value. It should just be the card number and expiration date that have to match your sandbox test card details.